# Batch: "usebackq" not expected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this code:

```
setlocal enableextensions
for "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b`) do echo * %%i
endlocal
```

Which I want to do is pretty simple: print the contents of current directory with `*` prefix. Something like this:

> ```
> * .idlerc 
> * .oracle_jre_usage
> * .swt
> * Searches
> * Contacts
> * Downloads
> * My Directory
> * Documents
> * Desktop
> * Favorites
> * Images
> * Saved Games
> * Music
> * 3D Objects
> ```

But, when executed, it says:

> "usebackq" not expected at this time

I'm new with for statements in Batch. Can someone help?

Comment: Use `for /F "usebackq" ...`

Comment: don't edit the answer to mark it solved. Just clicking the accepted mark is enough

Comment: Read the help for the FOR command.  If you use the `/D` option with the FOR command then all you need to do is use the asterisk for the IN clause.  Your code and the answer you accepted will enumerate **files and folders**.

Comment: @squash I wanted to enumerate both files and folders, but I didn't have any files in that _example_ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FOR /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and you don't need to use quotes* on your option here because there are no spaces in it:

```
setlocal enableextensions
FOR /F usebackq %%i IN (`DIR /B`) DO ECHO * %%i
endlocal
```

<sup>**Leaving the quotes in wouldn't do any harm though*</sup>

Comment: Why you should ommit the quotes? In the most cases you want quotes around the options

Comment: It still stands, this is the only case where you can safely omit the quotes. Even a simple option like `tokens=1` need quotes or other escaping. You should always use quoes for the options, only in the rare case of using a quote as delimiter character you can't use surrounding quotes

Comment: I'm not saying _you **should** omit_ - I'm just saying they aren't needed here, which they aren't. I'm not talking about other use cases. Your point is completely valid - I'm not disputing that.

Comment: To add to jebs comment, it s to mention that in case there is a dir/file with spaces in it only the first token is displayed. You either need `"tokens=*"` or `"delims="` to get the whole entry.

Answer (score 1):

I see your sample shows only directory entries, no files so this might be better.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ') do echo * %%i
```

If using single quotes you don't need the `"usebackq"`

Comment: I wanted to enumerate both files and folders, but I didn't have any files in that example folder.

Comment: Then @Macro Man's Batch is fine as long you don't havbe Names with spaces. I changed my above version